# Проблема с плагином jQuery mmenu

Tags: jquery, плагин

Есть лендинг. Попробовал сделать меню с помощью jQuery-плагина "mmenu" и видимо что-то делаю не так. Проблема заключается в следующем:
  при клике по пункту меню происходит переход в нужную часть страницы, но на долю секунды. После чего снова отображается верхняя часть сайта.
Вот код с настройками плагина:

[image: код настройки плагина]

Вот разметка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кхм, кхм. Это что? Мне хотелось взглянуть на html. И, пожалуйста, не картинками. Вы можете создать работающий пример, используя кнопку "Фрагмент кода ..." в редакторе вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо за то, что откликнулись. Я нашёл ошибку у себя. У меня в проекте оказалось два файла плагина mmenu (jquery.mmenu.js и jquery.mmenu.all.js).  Из-за этого на выходе они оба попадали в скомпилированный файл libs.js и поэтому плагин работал некорректно. Ещё раз спасибо за отклик!!!